# Log file's modified date is not updated although the log file is written successfully

Tags: c#, log4net

My log file's modified date is not updated.
I have to re-open and close (without modifying anything) the log file to change the modified date.
I used log4net framework to log.
Do I need to close or remove all Appenders after logging something to the file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [DateModified isn't updated while StreamWriter is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219705/date-modified-isnt-updated-while-streamwriter-is-open)

Comment: Thank you @JohnWu, however I didn't use any StreamWriter in my application so I think there could be other causes.

Comment: its nothing to do with streamwriter, its to do with a file handle and the way the operating system and filesystem work, what does your log4net config look like

Comment: I think there's a pretty good chance that Log4Net uses some flavor of file stream under the covers, so I think it's relevant. But it's not the answer, since you can't exactly rewrite Log4Net, so I am not marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: Also relevant: [Log4net log file modification date older than log entry date. Time machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901160/log4net-log-file-modification-date-older-than-log-entry-date-time-machine?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried calling [Flush](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_LogManager_Flush.htm)?

Comment: Hi @TheGeneral, my appender type is `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender`

Comment: Hi @JohnWu, I'll try it thank you in advance. In addition, I've already read this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901160/log4net-log-file-modification-date-older-than-log-entry-date-time-machine?rq=1) also.

Comment: I've found the root cause that my own app held the log file so when my app was turned off, the modified time was updated immediately. In my opinion,it could be related to concurrency. Thank you for all of your suggestions, it's very helpful to me.

Comment: does anybody know if this is the case of IIS logs?